# Dynamic HTML Table Handling in Selenium with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, selenium, html-table

I'm trying to create an array with values from a TD, through findelement, but I'm not able to get the result. Could anyone help me to resolve this? Thank you very much in advance

```
  const myvar = new Array();
  await driver
    .findElements(By.xpath('//table[@id="detail"]/tbody/tr'))
    .then((rows) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i]
          .findElement(By.tagName('td'))
          .getAttribute('innerHTML')
          .then((txt) => {
            myvar.push(txt);
          });
      }
    });

  for (var x = 0; x < myvar.length; x++) {
    console.log(myvar[x]);
  }
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the `<table>` element.